# PyCharm v4.5 cannot import name 'request'

Tags: python, csv, importerror

Whenever I run this code:

```
from urllib import request

goog_url = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=TSLA&d=4&e=20&f=2015&g=d&a=5&b=29&c=2010&ignore=.csv'

def download_stock_data(csv_url):

    response = request.urlopen(csv.url)
    csv = response.read()
    csv_str = str(csv)
    lines = csv_str.split("\\n")
    dest_url = r'goog.csv'
    fx = open(dest_url, "w")
    for line in lines:
        fx.write(line + "\n")
    fx.close()

download_stock_data(goog_url)
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Luke/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/Luke/PycharmProjects/untitled2/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib import request

ImportError: cannot import name request
```

I have tried installing 'request' modules, but the installations keep failing. What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to this stuff, but I've tried a bunch of other possible solutions I found on here without any success.

Comment: `urllib.request` is a Python 3 module; it's not there in Python 2.7.

Comment: Google will block requests from Python scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
from urllib3 import request
```

Works on Python 2.7