# Getting this error while installing the 'request' module of Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Error message:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement request (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for request

!pip install request
!pip install html5lib
!pip install bs4
```

Comment: This can't be the first question of this kind. Where is the canonical duplicate?

Comment: A candidate: *[Python error when attempting to install 'request' package using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930315/python-error-when-attempting-to-install-request-package-using-pip)*. For example, from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930315/python-error-when-attempting-to-install-request-package-using-pip/62971876#62971876): *"There is a* ***typo*** *in the article."* and *"at some point in time at least the request (without the s at the end) package contained some malware:"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python error when attempting to install 'request' package using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62930315/python-error-when-attempting-to-install-request-package-using-pip)

Comment: There is a *real* price to be paid for typos. Related: *[Several malicious typosquatted Python libraries found on PyPI repository](https://thehackernews.com/2021/07/several-malicious-typosquatted-python.html)*

Comment: More duplicates and similar: *[No matching distribution found for multiple packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927162/no-matching-distribution-found-for-multiple-packages/63344555#63344555)* (*"You probably unintentionally had request instead of requests in your requirements.txt file."*), *[PyCharm v4.5 cannot import name 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30339324/)*, and *[PIP Install request RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315868/)* (*"Do you actually mean to install request and not requests?"*)

Comment: The command line of the latter (SO 44315868) is `pip install request`. From SO 62927162 (my emphasis): *"These projects* (***request***, ***get***, ***post***) *were removed by their author and no longer exist."*

Comment: It *may* be [more than a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315868/pip-install-request-runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-python-2-7/44317024#comment134786723_44317024). It was part of [a deliberate injection attack in 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748121/i-am-trying-to-install-setupfiles-package-from-pip/52032994#52032994). See also *[PyPI Python repository hit by typosquatting sneak attack](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/09/19/pypi-python-repository-hit-by-typosquatting-sneak-attack/)*. Perhaps there are still remnants of it out there?

Comment: What guide are you following? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: One guide that contains the typo is *[New and Improved Mac OS Tutorial, Part 1 (The Basics)](https://passthroughpo.st/new-and-improved-mac-os-tutorial-part-1-the-basics/)*. But it is probably not the one used in this case. From *[Improving risks and consequences against typosquatting on pypi](https://discuss.python.org/t/improving-risks-and-consequences-against-typosquatting-on-pypi/5090)*.

Answer (score 1):

This is [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (with an "s"), hence: `pip install requests` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
python -m pip install requests
```

Maybe you mean *requests* and not *request*!

Answer (score 0):

This module name is *requests* so you should type `pip install requests`.