# How can I download a PyPI repository which only contains packages for Python 3.6.8, 3.8.6, 3.10.6 with Bandersnatch to host in Offline Lab?

Tags: python, cdn, rsync, pypi, bandersnatch

I want to set up an offline PyPI repository for my homelab (disconnected from the Internet, only offline lab).

I want to download all *.tar.gz/[*.whl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuptools#Package_format) files that work only in three versions of Python (and not download everything in PyPI).

The official Python documentation suggested using Bandersnatch, but I have not had luck with it.

It downloaded about 1.1 TB of packages with the below configuration, but never downloaded the "requests" package (which is supposed to be requests-2.31.0.tar.gz or requests-2.31.0-py3-non-any.whl). These files did not get downloaded.

Is the following banderswitch configuration file correct?

#### Result of `/etc/bandersnatch.conf | grep -v '^;' | sed '/^$/d'`

```
[mirror]
directory = /mnt/mylabnas01/repos/pypi
json = false
release-files = true
cleanup = false
master = https://pypi.org
timeout = 10
global-timeout = 1800
workers = 5
hash-index = false
simple-format = ALL
stop-on-error = false
storage-backend = filesystem
verifiers = 3
compare-method = hash
[allowlist]
platforms =
    py3.6.8
    py3.8.6
    py3.8.7
    py3.10.6
```

---

When I used the above configuration file as "/etc/bandersnatch.conf". and ran **bandersnatch mirror** ... after ~5 days, it downloaded 1.1 TB of packages (as root):

```
du -sh ./pypi/web/*
```

Output:

```
0       local-stats
1.1T    packages
834M    simple
```

It created a folder which contained directories like this:

```
./pypi/web/simple/
./pypi/web/packages/a9/09/78fd02c25977348689dbec2040e92c93ce743073842132c0e9f9910a223e/flask_dance-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
./pypi/web/packages/91/c8/cfbf90d7d1d148c5e0be4744d98acf900ce14486257407dd0565c667b892/flaskconstructicon-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl
./pypi/web/packages/91/53/b0a9fcc1b1297f51e68b69ed3b7c3c40d8c45be1391d77ae198712914392/flask_sqlalchemy-3.1.1.tar.gz
./pypi/web/packages/91/6a/161c7730b8d55c88ec826d7b389098787939427c3202270cb9d07df73746/flask_image_search-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
./pypi/web/packages/91/cc/7b14c479b4631cfaf6d582cf9c3511717f6dc5df8fda7037b53da6f5cf43/aa_standingsrequests-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl
./pypi/web/packages/da/57/33191298260e491d1d4fea7e6a10fac124b6fc90b5fdbe368d32d31ee6a7/flask_sqlalchemy_whoosh-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
... and so forth.
```

There are zips/wheel files, so Bandersnatch did download the files, but when searching for "requests" it was not downloaded.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you want to get all packages that are *compatible* with Python 3.6.8 (as far as can be programmatically determined)? The way you phrase it, I can't quite tell if you're trying to also get Python itself. And what's the significance of also listing 3.8.6, 3.8.7, and 3.10.6 in your configuration file?

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for your response. My goal is only have packages for 3 versions of python.

that way in my homelab, my Debian10, Debian11, and Debian12 servers which have different versions of python can still do "pip install requests".

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion in my question, I cleaned up the title and made the question more clearer. Hope someone can assist me with this question.

I will try to continue to fix it, and if I find a solution, will post it here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that some packages will only be published for older versions of Python, but they are really forward-compatible with newer versions. This means you can't really restrict downloads to only some fixed Python version.

What you *can* do, however, is blacklist a bunch of the versions / platforms you don't need, to cut down the overall amount downloaded. For example:

```
[blocklist]
platforms =
    macos
    freebsd
    py2.4
    py2.5
    py2.6
    py2.7
```

Note that you can only specify Python versions up to the minor version. You can provide a patch version, but its seemingly ignored. For a complete list of supported platforms, [see the documentation here](https://bandersnatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering_configuration.html#platform-python-specific-binaries-filtering).

In addition, you can download only the latest  versions of each package. I wouldn't recommend X=1, because you'll run into buggy versions of packages that you want to skip or you'll find that some package explicitly disallows a specific version of some dependency that has known issues. Setting this to something like 3 or 5 is generally a good compromise between space and flexibility. You may occasionally run into a package that wants only a very specific version of some dependency (which you may not have), but that's very uncommon. This configuration would look like:

```
[latest_release]
keep = 3
```

Finally, you can also restrict by package size, to exclude some of the excessively large packages that just bundle large amounts of assets with the core package. I personally would not recommend this—you'll find that you accidentally drop some common packages like [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) and [SciPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy). You can use it as long as you set the threshold high enough, but you need to verify that you haven't dropped anything crucial if so. For completeness, here's what that option would look like:

```
[size_project_metadata]
max_package_size = 1G
```

The corresponding plugin names for each of these filters is as follows:

```
[plugins]
enabled =
    exclude_platform
    latest_release
    size_project_metadata
```

Additionally, I would recommend that you enable `json = true` under the `[mirror]` section. It doesn't really use that much extra space, and makes your life simpler, and also enables you to setup `pip search` functionality if you want that.

My recommendations above come from personal experience using Bandersnatch to manage my own offline mirror. I keep everything Python 3 that are on any OS platform I use, the latest five versions, and no package size limits. It works very well, and I can only remember one package that I had issues with due to over-restrictive dependency declarations, which I resolved by forcibly installing both the newer version of the dependency and the package itself with `pip install --no-dependencies PACKAGE`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This comment explained everything in very good detail. 

After running bandersnatch, it still did not download the "requests" package, even though I expected bandersnatch to download it via `bandersnatch mirror`.

I decided to just use everything bandersnatch downloaded, and then use "Morgan" to download "requests" individually. https://pypi.org/project/morgan/

This is my ideal solution. To recap:
1) Use bandersnatch - to fetch everything, via config (with Peter's tweaks above).
2) Use morgan - to fetch the "requests" package afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Three spaces are always available:

1. The Python main repository, of which the closest download is to you.
2. If not on PyPI, look for it on js territory
3. If not there, then that app is either not worth looking to or you have one very brilliant idea.

Comment: What is "js territory"?

Comment: Re *"not worth looking to"*: '[Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)' is notable. It has its own tag here, with [21,846 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-requests). Enough to [be typosquatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&amp;lq=1#comment134785674_76440240) (or misspelled by pure sloppiness (though it is not the best of names)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen And is on PyPI, of course, so technically that doesn't contradict what's in this answer. That said, the "answer" has almost nothing to do with the question. If the main PyPI repository were available to the asker in their use case, they wouldn't be asking.

Answer (score -4):

Do this:

```ini
    [plugins]
    enabled =
        requires-python
    
    [requires-python]
    python_versions =
        3.6.8
        3.8.6
        3.10.6
```

Comment: Please do not delete an answer because it has been downvoted and then repost the identical answer again.  If you feel that your original answer is worth posting, then undelete it.  In both cases, your answers have likely been downvoted because they have no *explanation* of what this does or why you expect this to solve the problem.